# UICollectionView cell delegate object is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, protocols

I have a custom cell in my UICollectionView, which has a delegate property in it.

```
protocol ReloadCollectionViewProtocol: class {
   func reloadCollectionView()
}

class ColorCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var delegate: ReloadCollectionViewProtocol?
}
```

My parent ViewController conforms to `ReloadCollectionViewProtocol`, and I assign the cell.delegate to self in `cellForItemAt` method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "colorCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! ColorCollectionCell
     cell.delegate = self
     return cell
}
```

And here is the protocol confirmation part:

```
extension ProductDetailsViewController: ReloadCollectionViewProtocol {
func reloadCollectionView() {
    collectionView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Why is my delegate always nil ?

Comment: Is there any button over your cell xib .  Also try to put delegate as weak to avoid retain cycles.

Comment: where are you using delegate?